# Mysql to insert and update several fields based on two tables

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert fields into a table when there is no match on the PRIMARY key Study_ID... and update the fields if there is a match (so as not to overwrite a row).

My current attempt is:

```
INSERT INTO dataouts.all_diagnoses  (Study_ID, ol1, ol2, ol3, ol4, ol5, ol6, ol7, ol8, ol9, ol10) 
SELECT Study_ID, Provisional_Diagnosis_1, Provisional_Diagnosis_2, Provisional_Diagnosis_3,
          Provisional_Diagnosis_4, Provisional_Diagnosis_5, Provisional_Diagnosis_6,
          Provisional_Diagnosis_7, Provisional_Diagnosis_8, Provisional_Diagnosis_9,
          Provisional_Diagnosis_10
  FROM SurveyGizmo.SurveyExportAll
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE values (ol1, ol2, ol3, ol4, ol5, ol6, ol7, ol8, ol9, ol10)
  SELECT Study_ID, Provisional_Diagnosis_1, Provisional_Diagnosis_2, Provisional_Diagnosis_3,
          Provisional_Diagnosis_4, Provisional_Diagnosis_5, Provisional_Diagnosis_6,
          Provisional_Diagnosis_7, Provisional_Diagnosis_8, Provisional_Diagnosis_9,
          Provisional_Diagnosis_10
  FROM SurveyGizmo.SurveyExportAll;
```

I know this isn't right, but was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of how to resolve this issue as it has been causing my a headache for some time now!

Thanks in advance

################

With a bit more perseverence... think this works :

```
insert into dataouts.all_diagnoses(Study_ID, ol1, ol2, ol3, ol4, ol5, ol6, ol7, ol8, ol9, ol10)
    select t1.Study_ID, Provisional_Diagnosis_1, Provisional_Diagnosis_2, Provisional_Diagnosis_3,
          Provisional_Diagnosis_4, Provisional_Diagnosis_5, Provisional_Diagnosis_6,
          Provisional_Diagnosis_7, Provisional_Diagnosis_8, Provisional_Diagnosis_9,
          Provisional_Diagnosis_10
    from SurveyGizmo.SurveyExportAll t1 left outer join
         dataouts.all_diagnoses t2
         on t2.Study_ID = t1.Study_ID
     on duplicate key update ol1 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_1,
                             ol2 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_2,
                             ol3 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_3,
                             ol4 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_4,
                             ol5 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_5,
                             ol6 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_6,
                             ol7 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_7,
                             ol8 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_8,
                             ol9 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_9,
                             ol10 = t1.Provisional_Diagnosis_10
                             ;
```

Seems to work so far .. thanks everyone for any input you gave.

Comment: ODKU acts with one row, not with rowset. So it cannot contain SELECT query, it must consist from a lot of SET operators which assigns the values to separate columns of row which causes duplicate violation.

Comment: From the other side - you replace all field values of old record with new values - so [`REPLACE INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) instead of `INSERT INTO .. ODKU` may be more safe.

Comment: Thanks Akina... think my rework works now wihtout doing a lot of update / set operators.  And I can't use replace as I distinctly do not want to erase any information already in the row linked to the PRIMARY key.